# Is it correct to say "Her belly button sticks in/out" in everyday English?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

In some cultures, if you have a belly button that looks like a hole, your belly button is thought to be beautiful, but if it protrudes, it is not beautiful.

Is it correct to say "**Her belly button sticks in/out**" in everyday English?

Comment: The unjudgemental words *inny* and *outy* are often used instead. (Did we really need the pictures? )

Comment: @OldBrixtonian, “inny” and “outy” are not found in formal dictionary. Are they locale-specific? Can we say something that every dialect or every English person can understand?

Comment: It didn't sound as if you were looking for formal English! Formally it is called a [navel](https://www.lexico.com/definition/navel) not a belly button. Inny and outy are informal. I discover they can also be spelt with - ie. Lexico: [innie](https://www.lexico.com/definition/innie) - [outie](https://www.lexico.com/definition/outie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use various levels of formality:

> To a small child, or an adult to whom you don't mind talking childishly
>
> You have an outie, and your sister has an inny

> Generally
>
> My son has a protruding navel (or a navel that pokes out) and my
> daughter has a sunken one (or one that is sunk in or depressed)

> In formal or medical writing
>
> The male child's navel is everted, and the female sibling's is
> inverted

Comment: are  'inverted' (sunken) and 'everted' (poking out) everyday English because I could not find “inny” and “outy” in formal dictionary?

Comment: Inny and outy are informal childish slang. You are unlikely to find them in dictionaries.

Comment: Those words are understandable by most people.

Comment: maybe, "sunken" and "poke out" are best. 'inverted' and 'everted' are a bit formal I think

Comment: @Michael Harvey Inny and outy are informal. So is belly button. There are Lexico references above.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I wrote "to a small child". If you want to provide an answer, with references, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

“His/her belly button sticks out” is correct, but we do not typically say “sticks in”. “Goes in” might work, but it is more common to say that “He/she has an innie belly button.”

Comment: +1, maybe worth mentioning that “innie” and “outie” (or however we’d actually spell them!), are both common (opposing) terms to describe this (at least in the UK).

Comment: “innie” and “outie” are not found in formal dictionary. Are they locale-specific? 

Can we say something that every dialect or every English person can understand?

Comment: I can say with confidence that every American English speaker (native speakers) would know the terms, as they are taught and used extensively when we are very small children curious about our bodies.  The words are less used as you grow older, as it's typically not seen as polite to comment on-- at all.  I mean, not even that it's rude (although it is), just that it's *childish*, so even amongst very rude people it doesn't get discussed a lot.

Comment: I can't say for certain for other English dialects, such as British or Indian English, but I *suspect* the situation is similar, and that the words would be universally understood... but also that they are considered childish, and the topic at large to be rude.